# Federated Single Sign-On SAML 2.0 with ITfoxtec Saml2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

**What is Single Sign On (SSO)?**

Single sign-on (SSO) is a session and user authentication service that permits a user to use one set of login credentials (e.g., name and password) to access multiple applications.

Logging in multiple times can be eliminated with Single Sign On i.e. user has to login only once and can access web multiple applications.
Implementing SSO with ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 in ASP.NET MVC is very simple. Below is the step by step approach to implement it.

1. Open visual studio, create a ASP.net MVC Application
   [image]
2. add itfoxtec.saml2 and itfoxtec.saml2.mvc from nuget pacakges
   [image]
3. check the AuthController in your controller folder
   [image]
4. Set the basic setting 
   like Issuer url, Destination, AssertionConsumerServiceUrl
5. get the identity in AssertionConsumerService method using  given below code

   `var useridentity = saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity as ClaimsIdentity;
   var username = useridentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "username")
                     .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: Please use the updated [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) component instead of the old discontinued ITfoxtec.Saml2 component. More information [about  ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2](https://itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2).